# Include working copy in TortoiseHG's searches

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is it possible to show the working copy when doing searches in TortoiseHG?

I've got a large set of commits I'm cleaning to push at once (~30 commits: huge refactoring), so want to search for `descendants(283)` to reduce what I'm looking through (where I'm currently on 311).

Unfortunately, this removes the working copy, which I continually want to commit (locally) as I'm editing my history.

Is there any way to tell tortoise to show the working copy as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply recommend to open two instances of TortoiseHg, then arrange the windows as you wish.